# Is it dangerous to download Whonix?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, whonix, global-adversary

Is it dangerous to download Whonix. Could a global adversary or your ISP start monitoring you after they see you downloaded Whonix ?

Comment: *Could* they? Sure.

*Would* they? Unsure.

It depends on your circumstances, no one can give a definitive answer on this.